# Change Data Types for Dataframe by Schema in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe without schema and every column stored as StringType such as:

```
ID | LOG_IN_DATE | USER
1  | 2017-11-01  | Johns
```

Now I created a schema dataframe as `[(ID,"double"),("LOG_IN_DATE","date"),(USER,"string")]` and I would like to apply to the above Dataframe in Spark 2.0.2 with Scala 2.11.

I already tried:

```
schema.map(x => df.withColumn(x._1, col(x._1).cast(x._2)))
```

There's no error while running this but afterwards when I call the df.schema, nothing is changed.

Any idea on how I could programmatically apply the schema to df? My friend told me I can use `foldLeft` method but I don't think this is a method in Spark 2.0.2 neither in df nor rdd.

Comment: what is your current data frame schema ? use `df.printSchema()` and get. What is your output data frame schema ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you already have a list  `[(ID,"double"),("LOG_IN_DATE","date"),(USER,"string")]`, you can use **select** with each column casting to its type from the list

Your dataframe

```
val df = Seq(("1", "2017-11-01", "Johns"), ("2", "2018-01-03", "jons2")).toDF("ID", "LOG_IN_DATE", "USER")
```

Your schema

```
val schema = List(("ID", "double"), ("LOG_IN_DATE", "date"), ("USER", "string"))
```

Cast all the columns to its type from the list

```
val newColumns = schema.map(c => col(c._1).cast(c._2))
```

select all te casted columns

```
val newDF = df.select(newColumns:_*)
```

**Print Schema**

```
newDF.printSchema()

root
 |-- ID: double (nullable = true)
 |-- LOG_IN_DATE: date (nullable = true)
 |-- USER: string (nullable = true)
```

**Show Dataframe**

```
newDF.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+-----------+-----+
|ID |LOG_IN_DATE|USER |
+---+-----------+-----+
|1.0|2017-11-01 |Johns|
|2.0|2018-01-03 |Jons2|
+---+-----------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

> > My friend told me I can use foldLeft method but I don't think this is a method in Spark 2.0.2 neither in df nor rdd

Yes, `foldLeft` is the way to go

This is the `schema` before using `foldLeft`

```
root
 |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LOG_IN_DATE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- USER: string (nullable = true)
```

**Using `foldLeft`**

```
val schema = List(("ID","double"),("LOG_IN_DATE","date"),("USER","string"))

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
schema.foldLeft(df){case(tempdf, x)=> tempdf.withColumn(x._1, col(x._1).cast(x._2))}.printSchema()
```

and this is the `schema` after `foldLeft`

```
root
 |-- ID: double (nullable = true)
 |-- LOG_IN_DATE: date (nullable = true)
 |-- USER: string (nullable = true)
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Thanks for replying! I know foldLeft would work if schema is a List, but would this run in parallel cause the table I have is super large. Is there anything in Spark similar to foldLeft?

Answer (score 0):

If you apply any function of Scala, It returns modified data so you can't change the data type of existing schema.

Below is the code to create new data frame of modified schema by casting column.

1.Create a new DataFrame

```
val df=Seq((1,"2017-11-01","Johns"),(2,"2018-01-03","Alice")).toDF("ID","LOG_IN_DATE","USER")
```

2.Register DataFrame as temp table

```
df.registerTempTable("user")
```

3.Now create new DataFrame by casting column data type

```
val new_df=spark.sql("""SELECT ID,TO_DATE(CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LOG_IN_DATE, 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS TIMESTAMP)) AS LOG_IN_DATE,USER from user""")
```

4. Display schema

```
     new_df.printSchema                                                  
     root                                                                  
         |-- ID: integer (nullable = false)                                
         |-- LOG_IN_DATE: date (nullable = true)                           
         |-- USER: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you did:

```
schema.map(x => df.withColumn(x._1, col(x._1).cast(x._2)))
```

could work but you need to define your dataframe as a **var** and do like this:

```
for((name, type) <- schema) {
  df = df.withColumn(name, col(name).cast(type)))
}
```

Also you could try reading your dataframe like this:

```
case class MyClass(ID: Int, LOG_IN_DATE: Date, USER: String)

//Suppose you are reading from json
val df = spark.read.json(path).as[MyClass]
```

Hope this helps!